# Uploading media with the REST API

Tags: php, uploads, media, wp-api, curl

I am having trouble when uploading media to a WordPress site with the JSON REST API.

With the following code I can upload the photos, but no info is assigned to them, not even the name - in fact the name automatically becomes the URL and filename (without the extension).

```
$username = "ZX";
$password = "ZX";
$host = 'http://ZX.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media';
$data = json_encode($data);
$file = '/Users/xx.png';
$imagedata  = file_get_contents($file);
$process = curl_init($host); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:image/png','Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='.$file));
$return = curl_exec($process);
print_r($return);
```

How would I assign data, like the following, to the uploads?

```
$data = array(
  "status" => "draft",
  "title" => "Photo media",       
  "description" => "Photo media1",
  "media_type" => "image",
  "alt_text" => "alternate text"
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

> This is not possible via the API; you need to **fetch the image yourself**, and *send the data to the API* yourself.
>   Blockquote

<sup>– This quotes Ryan [on the GitHub–issue](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1768#issuecomment-160540932) mentioned in @Dan (deleted) answer.</sup>

### How to side load images

Note that the `media_sideload_image()` return value can be an instance of `\WP_Error` as well. You then just need to attach it to a post, which is quite simple:

```
$media = media_sideload_image( 
    'http://i.imgur.com/bcJvAj0.jpg', 
    $post->ID, 
    'Some image description', 
    'src'
);

if ( ! empty( $media ) and ! is_wp_error( $media ) ) {
    // reference new image to set as featured
    $attachments = get_posts( [
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_status'    => 'any',
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    ] );

    if ( is_array( $attachments ) ) {
        set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $attachments[0]->ID );
    }

    // Test print our image. The return value is the src of the sideloaded image.
    printf( '<img src="%s" />', $media );
}
```

### The internals

A short back trace through core that explains why you should stick with the API:

Take a look at the source of [`media_sideload_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_sideload_image/) to see it uses [`download_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/download_url/) internally, which uses [`wp_safe_remote_get()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_remote_get/), a wrapper for [`\WP_HTTP::get()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_http_get_object/). This means it offers the whole WP API while being quite safe, debuggable and easy to use. The return value of `download_url()` is the result of [`wp_tempnam()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_tempnam/), which takes all possible `/tmp` locations into account (there are plenty) and makes sure your location is *writeable*. The [`media_handle_sideload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_sideload/) will generate all needed attachment data and meta data.

Comment: Which is the cited question? Is this method still valid?

Comment: See update and GitHub–Issue link in the quote. And why would it not be valid? If you want to check again, just follow down the rabbit hole along the lines of _The internals_ and compare the current WP–version with the code linked here. That's not that hard.

Comment: Because this answer is from 2016. I just want to make sure that as of 2019, the REST API cannot deal with uploading files into `media` objects, hence one can focus on WP functions.

Comment: @Brethlosze as I said: Please take a look for yourself around core code. I do not have any fresh info on that topic as I am not working with WP much right now.